# Intel SCS Hardware Inventory Information

Tags: registry, intel, sccm

I have recently installed the Intel SCS Addon for SCCM 2012 which is functioning as intended. We required this as SCCM OOB Management out of the box does not support >= AMT 9.0.

I have imported the [MOF File](http://pastebin.com/GWf3W18D) that ships with Intel SCS, however when running the hardware inventory on configured machines, I get the following "RegKeyToMOF_32" entries on some of the items (Intel_AMT_ConfigurationInfo_Certificates, TLS Settings etc).

[image]

It seems that the MOF is configured to only look at 32 bit registry entries, as navigating to the x64 registry keys on the target machine reveals that information for those items exists.

Has anyone run into the same issue? I haven't been able to locate any Intel documentation that deals with alternate configurations for x64 redirected registries.

**Intel SCS Version: 9.0.23.10**

**Intel SCS SCCM Addon Version: 2.0.22.319**

Comment: Can you provide the following information:  Which version of Intel SCS are you using?  And you are running on an AMT 9.x system?  Which version of AMT 9 does your system have - 9.1 or 9.5?

Comment: There is an updated SCS 9 as of April 11: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=20921 and there is an updated SCS Addon for SCCM as well: Intel SCS Add-on for Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager 2.0:  https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=3051&DwnldID=23404&keyword=scs&lang=eng

Comment: The test machines I ran the inventory on are using AMT 9.0.5 - Interestingly, I check the registry for the x64 versions of the keys and they exist, so I'm wondering whether it has something to with the platform the WMI queries are run against in the MOF

Comment: There actually is a problem with some of the MOFs - no date for when the addon will be updated.  I am working on a way to get you the fixed MOF files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very unsatisfying answer to your question is that the MOF files have a lot of issues and a bug with the SCS team has been filed so this is a known problem.  I am not allowed to send you the edited mof files that may fix things for you but you can sumbit an issue with the support team directly and they can help you. Make sure you have **SCCM Addon** in the title and it will go to the right person.  Here is the link to the support site: [Intel Business Support](https://bizsupport.intel.com/index.cfm)  Click on "**Submit a Support Request**"

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted the support request and we'll see how it goes. Why hasn't an amended MOF been released yet if a fix exists?

Answer (score -3):

A version 2.1 of the Add-On released with major bug-fixes, please try to use it.
Intel SCS discovery is a 32 bit application but it stores the discovery information in both 32 and 64 bit registry locations, so rest assured - the mof files are directed to the correct place.